# Handling Jenkins status failure from exit code of Ansible plabook

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline, ansible-2.x, shutdown

Looking to handle system reboot on Linux with Ansible & running it as part of playbook along with other asks.

Seeing exit code as 4 & due to which Jenkins job is resulting in failure, though it has rebooted the machine.

Is there a way to handle this failure either from calling of ansible playbook from Jenkins or from within the playbook.

Tried even something like below apart from plain `reboot:` task as well, but still no luck. Kindly suggest alternative method of handling this.

```
- name: Reboot the machine
  shell: |
    shutdown -r now && exit 0 
  ...
  ....
```

Error is as per below

```
Reboot the machine ---------------------------------------- 1.02s
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 4
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Please see the [`reboot`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/reboot_module.html) module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the given description, task and error message

```
ERROR: script returned exit code 4
```

the error itself means Error Code 4 `EINTR` `Interrupted system call` or even `Network Error` in your example,  the devices which Ansible connect to are going to restart faster than Ansible and the module `shell` can maintain his own connection. Meaning, close and disconnect the session.

You may try with

```yaml
- name: Schedule reboot in 1 min
  shell:
    cmd: "shutdown -r +1"
  register: result

- name: Show result
  debug:
    var: result
```

or better [`reboot` module – Reboot a machine](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/reboot_module.html).

**Further Reading**

about an approach which was used in the past for Linux systems

- [How to automate system reboots using the Ansible](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/automate-reboot-ansible)

and

- [How to use Linux shell command exit codes](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/linux-shell-command-exit-codes)